# Why does Arduino (Mega 2560) display 5 less loop iteration result in port monitor?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get 20 values into the port monitor, but it only displays 15 values and there is no line with END where is my error?

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int
main(void)
{
    Serial.begin(19200);

    short z = 0;

    while (z < 20) {
        Serial.println("Value - " + String(z));
        _delay_ms(100);
        z++;
    }

    Serial.println("*****END*****");
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code look OK to me. But I'm not sure about the memory usage of the class `String`, which you use to build these intermediate strings to output. Could it be an allocation problem? What happens if you divide the single output statement into two separate statements to print the string literal and the loop variable?

Comment: Thank you for participating, everything is fine with the String, I think this is a Serial, but my skills are not enough.

Comment: I don't think so. The methods of `Serial` should block if its internal buffer is full. What is your suspicion? What do you think happens? -- Did you try to insert another delay in the last `while`?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/issues/53 I saw a lot of this and decided not to spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: Well, but freezing is just one issue. Would you mind to check that your code freezes, too? You can use an LED. Another test would just send one character per loop to check on the amount sent. And so one, be creative!